# how to add left Zero's to current PageNumber in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i have the following problem by trying to add left zero's to the current pagenumber in crystal report 
for example PageNumber shows me "1" but i want "001", ("2","002"...)

i been trying with

```
{@pagevar}=Right("000"&Númerodepágina1,3)
```

but it can't detect the PageNumber, (Crystal report is in spanish version) 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create in your crystal report a formula like below (your own page counter) placed whenever you want to show the page counter

```
stringvar page := "00000000000";
numbervar lenght := len(totext(TotalPageCount, 0, ""));
numbervar lenght1 := len(totext(pagenumber, 0, ""));

"Page " & right(page,lenght-lenght1) & totext(pagenumber, 0, "") & " of " & totext(TotalPageCount,    0, "")
```

it will show desired result

Comment: thank you i'll adapt your solution but that's the main idea, i gonna mark it as solved, but it's  Right ("000"&totext(pagenumber, 0, ""),3)

Comment: well I did it in a dynamical way, so in case you have a 100 pages it will add 00 but if you have 1000 it will add 000. Also when you counter hit 10 it will remove a 0 to have 010 or 0010